SQL DATEADD function not working as expected
I am creating a Customers table and in order to add a Customer, the customer has to be over 21. I have added a CHECK on the date of birth. Its working fine for all dates except the exact date 21 years ago. The logic seems correct. I don't know why its doing that.
CREATE TABLE customers(
    customer_ID int,
    dob date CHECK (dob < DATEADD(YEAR, -21, GETDATE()))
);

INSERT INTO customers VALUES(1, '09/26/2003'); 

--works as expected.

INSERT not allowed.

INSERT INTO customers VALUES(1, '09/25/2003'); 

--This should be blocked. But it still allows INSERT

2024 - 2003 = 21 so it still satisfy the condition.

I am using SQL Server.

I can't reproduce your issue (at least when removing the time from the current date), see this sample fiddle. It seems you have another issue? If you still need help, please edit the fiddle and share the new url, so we can replicate your problem.

dob date CHECK (dob < cast(DATEADD(YEAR, -21, GETDATE()) as date)) works for me. But of course, these kind of constraints are a bad idea in my opinion. It's business logic so better enforce it outside of SQL Server

And is your logic even correct? In my country you count as 21 from your date of birth, not the day after i.e. I am 21 on my 21st birthday, any time of the day. (BTW you need to add the date that you ran your query to the question, because some of us are in different timezones and need to be able to reproduce your issue).

You also should (always) use a non-ambiguous date format.

Check out this fiddle and tell us why you think 09/25/2023 should be blocked

GETDATE(), its name notwithstanding, returns the current datestamp, including time.
Do you want to do the operation on just the current date?
   dob date CHECK DATEADD(year, -21, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))


I have done it with DATE as well. Same issue. If I run this SELECT CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, -21, GETDATE()) AS DATE);, it gives me the correct result. '2003-09-25'. So, when I am checking for dob<'2003-09-25', it should check for any dates before 09/25/2003. I am not using <=. I am using dob<'2003-09-25'. So it should fail on 09/25/2003.
